# EJB module can't use war classes

Tags: jboss, ejb, java-6, axis2c

I have an EJB module that needs to use classes from a WAR. The code compile succesfully, but I have a NotClassDefFoundError exception in runtime.
The reason cause I need this behaviour is because EJB has to execute the code from an axis2 client.
And this module needs to be Web cause I need to intercept the SOAPMessage, so I can define a Handler in axis2.xml.
The application is deployed on a JBoss 4.2.

Any suggestion is welcome.

I have an jar module doing the functions of the client, but I need to configure axis2 to intercept the SOAPMessage. So I created a new Web Proyect and configure it in EAR and his dependencies, so the code compile fine, but is there when I got the runtime exception.
I read documentation to set axis2 in the actual jar but I couldn't make it works.
I tried make an Interceptor reading EJB interceptor documentation, it didn't work.